# Reading several datasets

Tags: python, pandas

I need to read 8 datasets:

```
df01, df02, df03, df04, df05, df06, df07, df08
```

This is my current approach:

```
#Set up file paths

filepath_2_df01= "folderX/df01.csv"
filepath_2_df02= "folderX//df02.csv"
filepath_2_df03= "folderX//df03.csv"
filepath_2_df04= "folderX//df04.csv"

filepath_2_df05= "folderY/df05.csv"
filepath_2_df06= "folderY/df06.csv"
filepath_2_df07= "folderY/df07.csv"
filepath_2_df08= "folderY/df08.csv"

#Read files

df01= pd.read_csv(filepath_2_df01)
df02= pd.read_csv(filepath_2_df02)
df03= pd.read_csv(filepath_2_df03)
df04= pd.read_csv(filepath_2_df04)

df05= pd.read_csv(filepath_2_df05)
df06= pd.read_csv(filepath_2_df06)
df07= pd.read_csv(filepath_2_df07)
df08= pd.read_csv(filepath_2_df08)
```

Is there a more concise way of doing that?

Comment: look at `os.listdir`  or `glob` and get all the filenames(with the full path) in both the folders in a list. You will end up with 2 lists. Add both the list to a single list and iterate through the list and read_csv for each iteration in a list comprehension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `glob` for this:

```
import glob

dfs = []
for file in glob.glob('folderX/*.csv'):
    dfs.append(pd.read_csv(file))

for df in dfs:
    print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, it works nicely. However, when I append the dfs I no longer have the names of each dataset. Is there any solution for that?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You mean the name of the csv files? There's no easy way to get that unless you create a dict of the dataframe and the name.

Answer (score 0):

use glob

```
from glob import glob

filenames = glob('/**/df*.csv') #get list of filenames, starting with df, in a specific folder. ** will search for subfolders as well(folderX and folderY, in your case)

dataframes = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in filenames] # using list comprehension, get a list of dataframes.
master_df = pd.concat(dataframes) #Concatenate list of dataframes to get a master dataframe
```